# Syntax issues in IF construct : shell script

Tags: shell

I have only one condition to check. And i would like to use the if-else construct in shell script. How do i write it. Most of the docs show that the construct is doing multiple aspects thats why they use

```
if []; then
 echo "do something"
elif
 echo "somethingelse"
else
 echo "something 2"
fi
```

But in my case i am writing my construct like the below. It gives syntax issues.

```
#!/bin/sh
hadoopFileList=`hadoop fs -ls /app/SmartAnalytics/Apps/service_request_transformed.db/sr_denorm_bug_details/ | sed '1d;s/  */ /g' | cut -d\  -f8`
destination="/apps/phodisvc/creandoStaging"

scpData()
{
 for file in $hadoopFileList
 do
  echo $file
  echo "copying file to the staging directory"
  hadoop fs -copyToLocal $file $destination
  sleep 2s
  echo "deleting the file"
  echo ${file##*/}
 done
}

if [[ -d "$destination" ]]; then
#file exists copy data
 scpData()
else
#else create directory and copy data
 mkdir -p $destination
 scpData()
fi
```

Comment: `mkdir -p` already does nothing (successfully) when the directory exists.  Why do you have the `if` at all?

Comment: @DavisHerring comments were written for stackoverflow users sake.

Comment: One Reason: You should not call your function with `()` 

wrong: `scpData()`
right: `scpData` 

only function definition needs `()`

Comment: @PS. wow thanks. I have been coding in java and other languages. I was not able to understand why the script was failing. Thanks for noticing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not call your function with (), only definition needes them.

wrong:

```
myFunction() {
echo "This line is from my Function"
}

myFunction()
```

Right way:

```
myFunction() {
echo "This line is from my Function"
}

myFunction
```

Answer (score 0):

As PS. mentioned, a bash function like `scpData` should be called without `()`. 
Other than that, your `if[];then ... else ... fi` syntax is correct. 
Thus your if-loop will work as:

```
if [ -d "$destination" ]; then
    scpData
else
    mkdir -p $destination
    scpData
fi
```

In this particular case, however, the if-loop is not necessary, 
because mkdir's `-p` option does check the condition. 
i.e., it only makes directory *if it doesn't exist*.
So I re-wrote your if-loop (without using if-else-fi) as following:

```
mkdir -p $destination
scpData
```

which does the same thing!